# Why does the "Filter" parameter on the Need Answer tab get saved, but nothing else does?

Tags: discussion, bounties, new-nav

I was browsing SO and got really confused when I saw there was only 1 bounty active.

[image]

It turns out, the Need Answer "tab" was saving my filter and not updating the bounty count for other "tabs"

[image]

Was this the intended behavior?

It does not save the filter on the "New" tab (can see `filter` seen by clicking on a tag), and none of the other navigation settings such as `show` or `sort` gets saved.